# Narrow down width in weblayout view in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-editors

when I write texts for my website I like to use the weblayout view in MS Word. However, the text expands over the complete width of the screen. If I could narrow it down so that it only expands as much as it does on my website (1024 pixels for instance), that would enable me to actually get an idea of how the text will display on my website. Is there a way to do that?